# How do I save and later load my NLTK classifier?

Tags: python, nltk, pickle

I am trying to perform sentiment analysis on movie reviews.

The following code is inside the function:

```
classifier = nltk.classify.SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())

classifier.train(train_set)
```

How do I save it and load it when I am using it later? And where should I put the pickle functions in my code?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you want to save the classifier object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pickle` when saving and reading the documents after running `nltk`.
First, you need to import the module.

```
import pickle

classifier = nltk.classify.SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
classifier = classifier.train(train_set)
```

For saving:

```
with open("filename", "wb") as infile:
    pickle.dump(classifier, infile)
```

For reading:

```
with open("filename","rb") as outfile:
    docs = pickle.load(outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pickle`.

For writing:

```
import pickle as pkl
clf = nltk.classify.SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
clf.train(X_train,y_train)
with open('clf.pkl','wb') as myfile:
    pkl.dump(clf,myfile)
```

For reading:

```
import pickle as pkl
with open('clf.pkl','wb') as myfile:
    clf = pkl.load(myfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save:

```py
def save(name,data,type='.dat'):
    name+=type
    pickle.dump(data,open(name,'wb'))#will create file if doesn't exist,will update file if there is such file
```

Load:

```py
def load(name):
    return pickle.load(open(name,'rb'))#will raise error if no such file exists
```

Example:

```py
save('myFile','foo')
print(load('myfile.dat'))#remember .dat !
#will prints 'foo'
```

You need to import pickle first then you can save anything